# Unpivot data excel with merged column using SSIS

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, ssis, flat-file

I'm using SSIS to export from Excel to text and in my case, I need to export  where the file contains merged columns anyone can help or have suggest for my case?

*Input Excel*

```
      A           B         C        D      E
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  Shop Name  |      Monday     |     Tuesday     |
|             +---------+-------+---------+-------+
|             | Jackson | Steve | Jackson | Steve |
+-------------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
| 7Eleven     | 11      | 30    | 23      | 21    |
+-------------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
| Delta Shop  | 43      | 12    | 33      | 2     |
+-------------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
```

*Output Expected*

```
+-------------+---------+-------------+-------+
|  Shop_Name  |   Day   | Member_Name | Point |
+-------------+---------+-------------+-------+
| 7Eleven     | Monday  | Jackson     | 11    |
+-------------+---------+-------------+-------+
| 7Eleven     | Monday  | Steve       | 30    |
+-------------+---------+-------------+-------+
| Delta Shop  | Monday  | Jackson     | 43    |
+-------------+---------+-------------+-------+
| Delta Shop  | Monday  | Steve       | 12    |
+-------------+---------+-------------+-------+
| 7Eleven     | Tuesday | Jackson     | 23    |
+-------------+---------+-------------+-------+
| 7Eleven     | Tuesday | Steve       | 21    |
+-------------+---------+-------------+-------+
| Delta Shop  | Tuesday | Jackson     | 33    |
+-------------+---------+-------------+-------+
| Delta Shop  | Tuesday | Steve       | 2     |
+-------------+---------+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: Would ne nice to see what you tried bit good question

Answer (score 2):

Using oledb and ACE driver (Microsoft Office) to read excel file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ConsoleApplication124
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=c:\\temp\\test.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\"";
            string query = "Select * From [Sheet1$]";

            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connStr);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            string[] days = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.Skip(1).Select(x => (x == DBNull.Value) ? string.Empty : ((string)x).Trim()).ToArray();
            string[] people = dt.Rows[1].ItemArray.Skip(1).Select(x => (x == DBNull.Value) ? string.Empty : ((string)x).Trim()).ToArray();
            int numberDays = days.Where(x => x != string.Empty).Count();
            int numberPeople = people.Where(x => x != string.Empty).Distinct().Count();


            string[] columnNames = { "Shop_Name", "Day", "Member_Name", "Point" };
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
            for (int row = 2; row < dt.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                string[] columns = dt.Rows[row].ItemArray.Select(x => (x == DBNull.Value) ? string.Empty : ((string)x).Trim()).ToArray();

                string shop = columns[0];

                for (int col = 1; col < dt.Rows[row].ItemArray.Count(); col++)
                {
                    object point = dt.Rows[row].Field<string>(col);
                    if (point != null)
                    {
                        string pointStr = ((string)point).Trim();
                        int dayIndex = numberPeople * ((col - 1) / numberPeople);
                        string day = days[dayIndex];
                        string person = people[col - 1];

                        string[] outputData = { shop, day, person, pointStr };
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", outputData));
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: This is very good solution for the c# portion. Additional SSIS steps are to add an Output with the 4 output columns instead of writing out to console. +1 from me

Comment: I wasn't sure what the text format should be so I just wrote CSV lines to the console.  It should be easy to write data to a file in any format you want.  The posting shows vertical and horizontal lines and wasn't sure if they should be in the file.