# How to read data from large multiple excel worksheets in to a list using C#

Tags: c#, excel, linq

I have two large worksheets of data(25k rows) in a single excel file.
The worksheet data is in the following format.

## **Sheet1**:

### Info| ID | Info Desc| Info Type   | Data Type   | Rate Format

25  | 5  | Expense  | Salary      | Numeric     | $$$.$$

250 | 2  | Meals    | Lunch       | Numeric     | $$$$.$$

350 | 25 | Detail   | More Detail | Text

375 | 25 | Test |   | 12345       | Text

## **SHEET2**:

### Info| ID | Cert Num | Cert Val

25  | 5  | 2500     | 25000.00

250 | 20 | 2222     | 5200.05

350 | 25 | 32156    | 2500

375 | 25 | 12564    |  25.00

I'm trying to 
1) read rows in to two separate lists and 
2) Merge data in to one common list using common properties (Info & ID) on both worksheets.
3) Check/validate each row data. Like, check if any datatype is incorrect or blank.

I have tried to read rows in to seperate lists but it is taking longer times to finish reading first worksheet itself. Please assist on how to efficiently read both these worksheet data into one list and validate each column value.

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlSheet1WorkSheet;
            Excel.Worksheet xlSheet2WorkSheet;

            int iRow;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(wsFile);
            xlSheet1WorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets["SHEET1"];
            Excel.Range xlSheet1Range = xlSheet1WorkSheet.UsedRange;
            int xlSheet1RowCount = xlSheet1Range.Rows.Count;
            int xlSheet1ColCount = xlSheet1Range.Columns.Count;


            xlSheet2WorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets["SHEET2"];
            Excel.Range xlSheet2WorkSheetRange = xlSheet2WorkSheet.UsedRange;
            int xlSheet2RowCount = xlSheet2WorkSheetRange.Rows.Count;
            int xlSheet2ColCount = xlSheet2WorkSheetRange.Columns.Count;

            List<ImportSheet1> Sheet1CombinedList = new List<ImportSheet1>();

            List<ImportSheet2> Sheet2sCombinedList = new List<ImportSheet2>();


         //   DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Now;
            for (iRow = 2; iRow <= xlSheet1RowCount; iRow++)  // START FROM THE SECOND ROW.
            {
                ImportSheet1 Sheet1Info = new ImportSheet1();
                Sheet1Info.Info = xlSheet1Range.Cells[iRow, 1] != null ? Convert.ToString(xlSheet1Range.Cells[iRow, 1].Value2) : null;
                Sheet1Info.ID = xlSheet1Range.Cells[iRow, 2] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(xlSheet1Range.Cells[iRow, 2].Value) : 0;
                Sheet1Info.InfoDesc = xlSheet1Range.Cells[iRow, 3] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(xlSheet1Range.Cells[iRow, 3].Value) : 0;
                Sheet1Info.DataType = xlSheet1Range.Cells[iRow, 4] != null ? Convert.ToString(xlSheet1Range.Cells[iRow, 4].Value2) : null;                
                Sheet1Info.RateFormat = xlSheet1Range.Cells[iRow, 4] != null ? Convert.ToString(xlSheet1Range.Cells[iRow, 4].Value2) : null;    

               Sheet1Info.InfoID = Convert.ToString(Sheet1Info.Info) + Convert.ToString(Sheet1Info.ID);
                Sheet1CombinedList.Add(Sheet1Info);

            }
//            DateTime dtEnd = DateTime.Now;

            for (iRow = 2; iRow <= xlSheet2RowCount; iRow++)  
            {
                ImportSheet2 Sheet2sInfo = new ImportSheet2();
                Sheet2sInfo.Info = xlSheet2WorkSheetRange.Cells[iRow, 1] != null ? Convert.ToString(xlSheet2WorkSheetRange.Cells[iRow, 1].Value2) : null;
                Sheet2sInfo.ID = xlSheet2WorkSheetRange.Cells[iRow, 2] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(xlSheet2WorkSheetRange.Cells[iRow, 2].Value2) : 0;
                Sheet2sInfo.CertNum = xlSheet2WorkSheetRange.Cells[iRow, 3] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(xlSheet2WorkSheetRange.Cells[iRow, 3].Value2) : 0;
                Sheet2sInfo.CertVal = xlSheet2WorkSheetRange.Cells[iRow, 4] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(xlSheet2WorkSheetRange.Cells[iRow, 4].Value2) : 0;

                Sheet2sInfo.InfoID = Convert.ToString(Sheet2sInfo.Info) + Convert.ToString(Sheet2sInfo.ID);
                Sheet2sCombinedList.Add(Sheet2sInfo);

            }
```

I would like to know how to read these rows faster and combine both these worksheet data in to one list using common property Info & ID.

Comment: For starters, *don't* use Excel Interop. That's several orders of magnitude slower than using eg ADO.NET and the Jet provider or ExcelDataReader. Trying to access sheets, cells and their properties in *another process* is hundreds of times slower than accessing a local object. `xlSheet1Range.Cells` is a cross-process call. `xlSheet1Range.Cells[iRow,4]` is *another* cross-process call.

Comment: BTW 25K rows isn't a lot of data. An Excel sheet can have up to 1M rows

Comment: The Interop is very very very slow.  The Interop using a text scripting language and data has to be converted to strings.  Use oledb like on the posting I answered last week : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57425248/unpivot-data-excel-with-merged-column-using-ssis/57427638#57427638

Answer (score 0, accepted):

25K rows is a small number of rows. Excel can hold up to 1M rows per sheet.

The delay is caused by the use of Excel Interop, not the size of the data. Interop calls are actually COM calls to a separate process. Every such call is 100s of times slower than accessing a local object. The line `xlSheet2WorkSheetRange.Rows.Count` contains *two* cross-process calls, one to get a reference to the Rows collection and one to reat the `Count` property from it. The same with `xlSheet1Range.Cells[iRow, 3]`.

You can use [ADO.NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306572/how-to-query-and-display-excel-data-by-using-asp-net-ado-net-and-visua) and the Jet OLEDB provider or a native .NET library like [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader). The advantage of a native .NET solution is that you don't need to install anything on the client machine.

You can use `ExcelDataReader` to read all the data directly into a DataSet, with the data from each sheet ending up in a separate table, eg :

```
using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
    {
        var result = reader.AsDataSet();

        var table1=result.Tables["Sheet1"];
        foreach(DataRow in table1.Rows)
        {
           //Do something with the row
        }
    }
}
```

An easy way to convert those rows to strongly-typed objects would be to use [LINQ To Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/single-table-queries-linq-to-dataset) :

```
var query1 = from row in table1.AsEnumerable()
            select new ImportSheet1
            {
                Info = row.Field<string>(0),
                ID   = row.Field<int?>(1)??0,
                InfoDesc = row.Field<int?>(2)??0,
                DataType = row.Field<string>(3),
                RateFormat = row.Field<string>(4)    
            };
var Sheet1CombinedList =query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm able to read the data in to two separate lists.How do I achieve 

2) Merge data in to one common list using common properties (Info & ID) from both worksheets. 3) Check/validate each row data. Like, check if any datatype is incorrect or blank.

Comment: You can iterate over the rows or use the LINQ to Datasets query I just posted

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the following error when excuting the last step:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.